# Interceptor checking for css and js

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc interceptor for security but it,s also checking for css and js also but I want ignore checking for css and js.

I have interception as below style in my XML file :

```
 <mvc:interceptors>
     <bean class="com.nfdil.loyalty.web.interceptor.SecurityManagerInterceptor" />
 </mvc:interceptors>
```

How can I ignore checking for css and js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
<mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
    <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/static/**"/>
    <bean class="com.nfdil.loyalty.web.interceptor.SecurityManagerInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptor>
```

You can find more detailed docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-interceptors)